# How to link a button to a special place on Image?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I've placed buttons and imageView on RelativeLayout, and these buttons are placed perfectly on Nexus 5: [How it looks on Nexus 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbITR.png)

But on Nexus One it changes a lot: [How it looks on Nexus One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA9PB.png)

Here's my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/main_menu_top" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/main_menu_center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView6" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView6">

        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/top_left_button"
            android:layout_width="105dp"
            android:layout_height="105dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_marginLeft="77dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="77dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_main_menu_port"
            android:text="Example" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/top_right_button"
            android:layout_width="105dp"
            android:layout_height="105dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_main_menu_port"
            android:text="Example"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/top_left_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bot_left_button"
            android:layout_width="105dp"
            android:layout_height="105dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/top_left_button"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/top_left_button"
            android:layout_marginBottom="39dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_main_menu_port"
            android:text="Example" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bot_right_button"
            android:layout_width="105dp"
            android:layout_height="105dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bot_left_button"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/top_right_button"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/top_right_button"
            android:background="@drawable/button_main_menu_port"
            android:lines="2"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:text="Example" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

However, these buttons need to be on positions of the rhombuses in this image.

Comment: Can you please post an image of your expected result?

Comment: Check screenshot with resolution of Nexus 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `fixed` layout `width` and `height` for buttons and also used `fixed` layout `margins`. Fixed values causes the problem because the `resolution` of `Nexus Five` and `Nexus One` are different.

**Solution:**

You can use `LinearLayout` with attribute `android:weightSum` and use `android:layout_weight` to buttons instead of fixed `width` and `height`.